# How can I redirect one 'vanity' domain to another domain via DNS?

Tags: dns

I have a domain for my 'vanity urls', lets calls it `ample.co`, and the subdomain `ex.ample.co` is used for the vanity urls (using Bitly). The address `ex.ample.co` via Bitly redirects to `example.com`, the main website/domain.

Using the DNS setup from registrar, how can I redirect `ample.co` to `example.com`?

Answer (score 1):

Add a CNAME for the root of ample.co which points to example.com

This will only do a DNS redirect. If the server hosting example.com doesn't support the URL ample.co in its list of header addresses, it won't display a page.

Another option would be to have an HTTP server for ample.com which does an HTTP Redirect to example.com.